# GCC - Label address return current EIP rather than real label address

Tags: c, gcc, osdev

In an attempt to write an OS, I need to get the address of the current function's end (right before epilogue) for task switching.
Concretely my problem is to get an EIP to assign to my newly created task (process) inside the copied stack. I have already managed to save/restore registers for a process, but I need to find what value the child process will have in it's EIP.

I used GCC's extensions to C standard : [Labels as Values](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html) and [Local Labels](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Labels.html)
From the documentation : *You can get the address of a label defined in the current function (or a containing function) with the unary operator ‘&&’. The value has type void *.*
and : *GCC allows you to declare local labels in any nested block scope. A local label is just like an ordinary label, but you can only reference it (with a goto statement, or by taking its address) within the block in which it is declared.*

```
pid_t fork(void)
{
    __label__ fork_end;
    ...
    task->regs.eip = (uintptr_t)&&fork_end;
    ...
    return task->pid;
    fork_end:;
}
```

GCC does compile it, with just warnings about non-standard code.
However when disassembled, gdb shows :

```
    task->regs.eip = (uintptr_t)&&fork_end;
0x00105008 <+87>:   mov    $0x105008,%edx
0x0010500d <+92>:   mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x00105010 <+95>:   mov    %edx,0x40(%eax)
...
    fork_end:;
    }
0x00105096 <+229>:  leave  
0x00105097 <+230>:  ret
```

I expect `task->regs.eip = (uintptr_t)&&fork_endl` to save`0x00105096` rather than `0x00105008`.
`CFLAGS` are `-O0 -std=gnu99 -fgnu89-inline -DDEBUG -ggdb3 -ffreestanding -fbuiltin` (warnings related options not shown here).

Commenting `__label__ fork_end;` changes nothing.

Comment: Please provide a reference to the gcc documentation about `&&` and state what it does in your understanding. It does not warn when using extensions. See [ask] and provide all required information.

Comment: Edited, and @Olaf, gcc warns about non-standard code with `-Wpedantic` option. Thanks for your advices.

Comment: Aha, I see. Using `-Wpedantic` with extensions sound like a bad idea. Anyway, your cast is implementation defined and an `uint32_t` is not rquired to hold a pointer, nor there is a 1:1 assignment. On a 64 bit system you are busted already. Use the correct types at least. Any reason you don't use a `void *` as a pointer, but an integer?

Comment: As a personal opinion: I don't see any sense in that code. You probably have an XY-problem.

Comment: @Olaf, I don't think I have an XY problem and anyway, I'm working on an OS to learn about the insides of OS, compilers, and hardware interaction. My goal is not to make a good OS but getting errors to learn from on the way. I encountered a behavior which I was not expecting to and so I want to understand what's going on. You can see my real question as _why GCC is not giving me what it is supposed to_ (from my understanding). This post is not about _how should I write a fork() implementation_ but _how can I get the address of a label with GCC's label as values extension_.

Comment: A dissection is not a good way to understand what a frog thinks. How about reading a book about compiler construction, etc.? Sometimes the old fashioned way is still the best. There is no use in the code above with modern compilers, even for learning. And trial&error in C is a very bad idea.

Comment: I think I may not have been clear on what precisely I'm looking for.
I'm not talking about trial&error but that errors are an unavoidable part of programming from which you need to learn, to fix it and improve your skills. And I'm (at least not currently) looking for learning about how compilers work but understanding how labels as values works. I have implemented my fork() in a few different ways but since I came across this extension from GCC without successfully using it, I want to understand why it doesn't do what, from the documentation, I thought it would.

Comment: Try removing the '__ label__' line. Looking over the local label docs, when referencing the label as a value it does not use this construct. Cannot currently test as I'm not at a computer.

Comment: Just use assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the compiler is optimizing out the label entirely as no code path ever leads to it. I have confirmed that moving the label to before the `return` statement and ensuring that there is actual code in-between the assignment and the label results in what I believe is your desired behaviour. Here is the code I put together to test:

```
void *fork(void) {
  __label__ fork_end;
  void *test = &&fork_end;

  test++;

  fork_end:
  return test;
}
```

Based on this, I would expect that you can indeed get what you want by re-working your code path slightly to ensure that the label point is reachable by any code path.

Comment: Since the caller process is not expected to reach this label, I had to use a never-true if to trick GCC and make it seen as reachable even if it is not.
Anyway thank you very much @joel-c